# Pentaho Report Design conditions

Tags: pentaho

I want to put one condition for the columns in the report. I am passing a parameter called "TEMPLATE", I want to make some of the columns in report visible only if the values of passed parameter lies IN ["A","B",C","D"]. I am putting it like:

```
=IF([TEMPLATE]IN("A";"B";"C";"D";"E");TRUE();FALSE());
```

But it says syntax error every time and doesn't work. Can someone please help me in making it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
=IF(IN([TEMPLATE];"a";"b";"c");TRUE();FALSE())
```

where is

```
IN(<condition>;<sample1>;<sample2>;...)
```

returns true if <condition> equals to one of the <sampleX>. Otherwise return false.